# How to add samba to startup applications

Tags: startup

I have samba installed on ubuntu 14.04 and I want it to start on system boot. Anybody help?

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run the following command in a terminal :

```
sudo update-rc.d samba defaults
```

Comment: I believe it is now called `smbd` instead of `samba`, at least in my Ubuntu 18.04...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways. I don't know about samba, but it worked for me in running some other services.

There are three ways to do it.

Alternative 1#     Creating New Script in `/etc/init.d/`

We can create new startup service by creating a new script inside the    init.d

directory

```
Note: Donot forget to make the script executable
```

Alternative 2#     By adding commands to `/etc/rc.local`

The technique is illustrated by the following example :

```
vi /etc/rc.local

/path/to/my/script.sh || exit 1
exit 0
```

Alternative 3#     The third way to achieve that is by adding an Upstart Job

```
    Create      /etc/init/myjob.conf

Add the following entries to the file


description "my Job"
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Here in description you can use any name. In the path of `exec` give the path of the samba binary.